# Python colorbars for multiple subplots

Tags: python, plot, subplot, colorbar

Suppose we want to plot a multiplot of 3 x 5 colorplot images with `plt.imshow()`. The first row contains some kind of data, the second and third one some other kind. The question is: Is there a way to plot the first on a common colorbar and the second+third rows on a different one, with the colorscale being identical for the two groups.

So far I the way I treated such problems was to "attach" the first colorbar to a single (e.g. the last) plot of the first row and the second colorbar to a single (the last plot) of the second and third rows. I would then set a colorscale that displays the data reasonably and run the code again, giving the color limits within the two groups already in the `plt.imshow()` call via `vmin`, `vmax`.

However this way the interactibility gets lost. So I'd like to know whether there's a pythonic way to attach the two colorbars to the entire first and second+third rows in such a way that there's some kind of handle that allows editing the color limits (e.g. via `set_clim`) so that all images in that group are simultaneously set to these limits.

Consider the example code below. One way could probably be some kind of list of image handles. In such a list in each iteration the next handle would be appended and then after the plot has been created, one might loop over that list, using `im1[i].set_clim()`.

```
im1 = []
im2 = []
for i in range(3):
  for j in range(nbins):
    pos = i*nbins + j + 1
    if i % 3 == 0:
      data = npts_lbins_map[j,:,:]
    elif i % 3 == 1:
      data = sigx_lbins_med_map[j,:,:]
    elif i % 3 == 2:
      data = sigy_lbins_med_map[j,:,:]
    plt.subplot(3,nbins,pos)
    if pos <= 5:
      im1.append(plt.imshow(data, interpolation='none', origin='lower', extent=[lonst_all.min(), lonst_all.max(), lathg_all.min(), lathg_all.max()]))
    elif pos > 5:
      im2.append(plt.imshow(data, interpolation='none', origin='lower', extent=[lonst_all.min(), lonst_all.max(), lathg_all.min(), lathg_all.max()]))
    if pos == 5:
      ax1 = plt.gca()
      divider1 = make_axes_locatable(ax1)
      cax1 = divider1.append_axes("right", size="5%", pad=0.05)
    elif pos == 15:
      ax2 = plt.gca()
      divider2 = make_axes_locatable(ax2)
      cax2 = divider2.append_axes("right", size="5%", pad=0.05)
    plt.xlabel('Stonyhurst longitude [deg]')
    plt.ylabel('latitude [deg]')
```

However I am interested in knowing whether there's some designated kind of group/container of image handles that already has the relevant attributes methods, which does not require looping, or whether there's a much more clever way.

In the example code from above the colorbar is not yet plotted, but this should be still possible with `plt.colorbar()` after the loop, since then we have the axis where it should be placed and also (supposed it exists) the mentioned image 'container'.

For demonstration purposes, you could use also 3 x 3 subplots with random matrices.

Thanks for the help!

P.S.: How do I increase the vertical size of the colorbar to fit the entire second+third rows instead of only the third row? Is there some possibility with `make_axes_locatable`?

---

PUSH: The question could also be formulated like this: Is there a matplotlib `mappable` (similar to `im`, but containing multiple of them) that can be passed to `plt.colorbar()` and that has a `set_clim()` attribute such that the color scale of all images is updated as well as the scale of the colorbar to the new color limits?